# Creating my shell: replace home directory with "~" in my prompt. Problem with replacing the home directory substring

Tags: c, shell, replace, directory, path

I have a problem trying to have the home directory be "~" in the prompt for my very own shell. I am getting the directory, strstr'ing it with the whole directory but when it is found and I want to change it to "~" for my prompt, the whole shell is segfaulting. Any idea how to change only the home directory from my directory path into ~? Here is a code example with memset, I also tried memcpy and strncpy/strcpy:

```
char *prompt_line(void) {

    if(last_status == 0){
        printf("[]");
        number_displayed++;
    }
    else{
        printf("[]");
        number_displayed++;
    }
    char *username = getlogin();
    char hostname[16];
    char directory[55];

    struct passwd *pw = getpwuid(getuid());
    const char *homedir = pw->pw_dir;

    getcwd(directory, sizeof(directory));

    char *ret = strstr(directory, homedir);
    memcpy(ret, "~", 6);

    gethostname(hostname, 64);
    sprintf(prompt_str, "-[%d]-[%s@%s:%s]$", number_displayed,  username, hostname, ret);
    return prompt_str;
}
```

Comment: Where did you declare `prompt_str`?

Comment: `memset()` will create something like `~~~~~~~~~~~~~`, not a single `~`.

Comment: You need to call `getcwd(directory, sizeof(directory))` *before* you call `strstr()`.

Comment: Sorry, I changed it now and it is working the very first time but segfaulting after

Comment: You need to check if `strstr()` returned non-NULL.

Comment: prompt_str is a static char array with value "$"

Comment: Okay I'll try it now

Comment: So if ret is non-NULL, I use memcpy and if it is NULL it means that the home directory was not found and in that case I display only the directory?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: Okay it works now for the first time, but when I "cd tests" for example the prompt only displays "~" instead of "~/tests"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`memcpy(ret, "~", 6)` is not correct. There are only 2 bytes in `"~"` (the `~` character and the null terminator), you can't copy 6 bytes from it.

You need to put the result in a new string to combine `~` with the remainder of the directory.

```
char prompt_dir[55];
char *ret = strstr(directory, homedir);
if (ret == directory) {
    if (strcmp(directory, homedir) == 0) { // in homedir, prompt is just ~
        strcpy(prompt_dir, "~");
    } else { // in subdirectory, prompt is ~/subdir
        sprintf(prompt_dir, "~/%s", directory + strlen(homedir) + 1); // skip past homedir and / character
    }
} else {
    strcpy(prompt_dir, directory);
}
gethostname(hostname, 64);
sprintf(prompt_str, "-[%d]-[%s@%s:%s]$", number_displayed,  username, hostname, prompt_dir);
```